# Determining the movie popularity for upcoming movies with neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a CSV data set consisting of a movie details per line.
These are: name, budget, revenue, popularity, runtime, rating, votes, date released.

I'm wondering how to split the data set into training, validation and testing sets?

Then of course, how to get some results?

It would be nice to get a brief step-by-step intro on where/how I should begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the nntool. In your case I guess curve fitting is appropriate. So use the nftool
Define your input and output in nftool then you can just randomly divide your data into training, validation and testing sets using the nftool. In the Nftool GUI you can choose how much to divide your data (80-10-10 or anything). Then you just follow the interface and then set the specifics of the network (e.g. the number of hidden neurons). Then you just train the network. After training you can plot the performance of the training and depending on the performance you can retrain or change the number of hidden neurons, percentage of the training data and so on. 
You can also check this :
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/gs/f9-35958.html